# How pass -t parameter to fabric8 docker-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, docker, fabric8, docker-maven-plugin

Here is plugin definition:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.26.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <registry>000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-aws-registy-0000000000000:latest</registry>
            <images>
                <image>
                    <name>my-image</name>
                    <build>
                        <tags>
                            <tag>000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-aws-registy-0000000000000:latest</tag>
                        </tags>
                        <dockerFileDir>${project.build.directory}</dockerFileDir>
                    </build>
                </image>
            </images>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

When I invoke cmd command:

```
sudo docker build -t 000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-aws-registy-0000000000000:latest .
```

Everythings works perfect. But when `docker:build` goal started from plugin I got:

```
 tag part '000000000000.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-aws-registy-0000000000000:latest' doesn't match allowed pattern '^[\w][\w.-]{0,127}$'
```

Why? What is the working configuration analog in fabric8 docker-maven-plugin for `docker build -t .`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<name>image-name:tag-name</name>` format inside image configuration.

Tag config inside build is the build time configuration. You will be able to use that tag only after you have locally built the image.